# Show only Softwares where User (subscribed = true)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on rails application where users can add one or more software.
These users can then subscribe (paid mode).

I would like to be able to display all paid user software only.

I tried several things and still can not find the solution.

for example:

```
Software.includes(:users).where(user: {subscribed: true})
```

EDIT:

Model USER:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :softwares
end
```

Model Softwares:

```
class Software < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

JoinTable

```
    class CreateJoinTableUsersSoftwares < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :softwares do |t|
      t.index [:user_id, :software_id]
      t.index [:software_id, :user_id]
    end
  end
end
```

ERROR with :

```
Software.includes(:users).where(user: {subscribed: true})


ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'Software' to association named 'users'; perhaps you misspelled it?)
```

Comment: What do the relationships in the models look like?  Can you post you model code for users and software, and the join table if you have one?

Comment: Could you also add the results / errors you're currently getting please? I've added an answer, though it's slightly speculative without the extra info. Hope it's useful anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my question.

I also tried with your Srack solution but the error is the same.

Thx for you help.

Comment: Thanks @ClydeT, really helpful. I've tweaked my answer to reflect this and think it should solve your issue. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Perfect it works! Arf I was so close!

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your error is here:

```
Software.includes(:users).where(user: {subscribed: true})
```

The `includes` should reflect the association, in this case a singular `user`. This is what's causing the error you're seeing.

Also, it's a common gotcha, but the association within the `where` clause needs to use the table name.

Try this:

```
Software.includes(:user).where(users: { subscribed: true })
```

This assumes you'll be using the info on the `user` elsewhere, i.e. in your view. If you don't need to access the record, rather just check the `user` for the query, you can switch `includes` to `joins` to improve the query's efficiency:

```
Software.joins(:user).where(users: { subscribed: true })
```

It's a separate topic, but there's a good read on it [here](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/01/24/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where).